# Scrolling with Drag and Drop Table in Fixed Width DIV

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I've got a bit of a problem i'm not able to solve.

Basically I have a drag/drop table in a DIV. The table is 5000px Wide and is placed within the div. The div that holds the table is 1000px wide, overflow is set to scroll.

```
 <div id="drag" style="width:1000px; overflow:scroll;">
     <table id="table1" style="width: 5000px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
       ...content
     </table>
 </div>
```

When I drag an element from within the table and arrive at the end of the div (@1000px) and i need to move to access parts outside the view it is not working for me. (image https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcdV4.png)

When i remove the 1000px Width on the containing div it works and let me drag and continues scrolling. So the code below works. But the Div will be 5000 px wide (same as table) I wish for the Div to be only 1000px Wide and the scrolling to occur within the div not accross the "page".

```
<div id="drag" style="overflow:scroll;">
         <table id="table1" style="width: 5000px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
           ...content
         </table>
     </div>
```

Can anyone help please?

FYI. I am usind the REDIPS Drag Drop JQuery Plugin for Tables.  http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/

thanks